# How to trace an image in illustrator and reduce it to only outlines of the edges between colors?

Tags: path, export, image-trace, outline

so bear with me here.
When I trace an image in Illustrator, there is the option of viewing just the outlines. I want to be able to output an image that is made up of solely these outlines themselves so I can work with them.
For example, I traced this photograph in black and white: [image]
But I'd like to export an image of these outlines in blue here(although I don't necessarily want them in this color):
[image]

I'd like to be able to do this with any photo: trace an image, and produce line art of the edges between colors. However, the outlines are only available as a 'view' option, and when I export the image, the outlines are omitted.

The only way I've been able to accomplish what I'm trying to do is by taking a screenshot of the outline and reuploading the screenshot into illustrator, then tracing it in Black and White mode. But I lose detail in the process and I feel like there must be an easier way.

I've been looking for this option for a while, and I'm surprised I can't find it online, as I can see it being useful for a coloring book effect, or a way of making an image cartoony by layering an outline over the original photograph.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Trace a colour photo
2. Press the Expand button
3. Set the fill to none, set a stroke colour and width.

Example

[image]